# Calcium carbonate minerals in marine organisms shells

Tags: biochemistry, marine-biology, bioinorganic-chemistry, minerals

Calcium carbonate minerals exist in seawater in two main phases: calcite and aragonite. While calcite is the most stable phase, it is aragonite that precipitates first in seawater because of the high magnesium content of the oceans today. But for a similar environment, e.g., tropical shallow water, some organisms have a calcitic shell while some other have an aragonitic one. How can organisms choose which phase composes their shell?

Comment: The two minerals differ only in crystal structure. changing the assembly proteins is enough. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232236795_Aragonite-associated_biomineralization_proteins_are_disordered_and_contain_interactive_motifs